# how to create barchart in python xlsxwriter that does not start at 0?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I found the following image that consists exactly the chart that I want to be able to create, however I can't figure out how to start the bar somewhere else than zero. Does anybody know how to solve this?

[image]

as mentioned below in the comments it is a line chart with up_down_bars.
How can I get an example of this to work?

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_line.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})

# Add the worksheet data that the charts will refer to.
headings = ['Number', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2']
data = [
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50],
    [30, 60, 70, 50, 40, 30],
]

worksheet.write_row('A1', headings, bold)
worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2])

# Create a new chart object. In this case an embedded chart.
chart1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Configure the first series.
chart1.add_series({
    'name':       '=Sheet1!$B$1',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7',
})

# Configure second series. Note use of alternative syntax to define ranges.
chart1.add_series({
    'name':       ['Sheet1', 0, 2],
    'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0, 6, 0],
    'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, 2, 6, 2],
})

# Add a chart title and some axis labels.
chart1.set_title ({'name': 'Results of sample analysis'})
chart1.set_x_axis({'name': 'Test number'})
chart1.set_y_axis({'name': 'Sample length (mm)'})
chart1.set_up_down_bars({
    'up': {
        'fill':   {'color': '#00B050'},
        'border': {'color': 'black'}
    },
    'down': {
        'fill':   {'color': 'red'},
        'border': {'color': 'black'},
    },
})
# Set an Excel chart style. Colors with white outline and shadow.
chart1.set_style(10)

# Insert the chart into the worksheet (with an offset).
worksheet.insert_chart('D2', chart1, {'x_offset': 25, 'y_offset': 10})


workbook.close()
```

Comment: *Q:  How can I get an example of this to work?*. The code you posted is straight from the documentation and it works as it is. I think you need to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes it works but there are no bars in my graph. So my question is how can I get the result of the image above in the question?

Comment: I ran the program above and I see the drop bars in the output. What version of Excel and XlsxWriter are you using?

Comment: You are right, I was on Mac OS X and in the Numbers app I can't see any bars. However on Windows with Excel 2010 it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that by "can't figure out how to start the bar somewhere else than zero" you mean that you don't want the Y-Axis to start from 0.

You can change that in the same way that you would in Excel: by changing the minimum value for the axis range. See the [`set_x_axis()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/chart.html#chart-set-x-axis) section of the docs and also [Working with Charts](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_charts.html).

```
chart.set_y_axis({'min': 10})
```

If that isn't what you are looking for then you probably need to clarify your question.

Also, to avoid confusion, the above image isn't a bar chart. It is a line chart with Up-Down bars. If you need a bar chart that is also shown in the docs and the examples.

Comment: hi @jmcnamara sorry I thought it is a combined chart.

Comment: No. This is an [example of a combined chart](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_chart_combined.html). Read through the Chart sections of the documentation and look at the chart examples in the docs and it should make sense.